# UITextField Hide Keyboard But Reamin First Responder?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I've subclassed a UITextField to display a UIDatePicker instead of a keyboard. Entering dates is something that happens often I our app. The problem occurs when another of our custom classes that accommodates the keyboard needs to know what the first responder.

Is there a way to remain first responder, whilst hiding keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, instead of subclassing, you should just make a custom inputView for your text field which uses a date picker as the custom "keyboard".  Then, it will remain the first responder and never even call the system keyboard in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to resign as responder (give up focus) to dismiss the keyboard.

**Edit:** It seems I lied. Try `[self.view endEditing:YES];`
FYI: It only works on iOS 3.2+

Comment: That should be `[self.view endEditing:YES];`